# Using Autodesk Forge in a web component

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to create a webcomponent that includes the forge viewer. Im sadly running into an issue where the forge viewer fails to properly load the lmvworker and the allstrings.json

It looks like the viewer has problems loading them when used into a webcomponent: viewer3D.js:40122 GET https://stacksnippets.net/lmvworker.js 404 (Not Found)

The viewer is fetched from developer.api.autodesk.com

To properly see the error open the inspector.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Core</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.14/webcomponents-hi.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zedero/forge-webcomponent/master/bim.html">
</head>

<body>
  <bim-viewer></bim-viewer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webcomponentjs still new to me, but manually loading `lmvworker.js` causes some problems. Can you try [removing this line](https://github.com/zedero/forge-webcomponent/blob/master/bim.html#L18)?

Comment: I removed it but sadly that didn't change anything.

Comment: are you able to provide a single .zip file with all files we need to repro the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/zedero/forge-webcomponent
Hope this will do :) Ive not tested it between browsers so I would recommend using Chrome

Comment: tried that, but the bim.html file shows as empty (using `npm serve` and running on Mac Chrome 69)

Comment: You need to open the index.html file. Else it will not load properly

Comment: Augusto Goncalves. Will you be present during the accelerator in Boston by any chance? Perhaps we could then have a look into this topic.

Comment: Yes, I will be in Boston :-)